# VB ASP.NET 4.0 - Adding Example to new web project

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to learn ASP.NET (after many years of using classic ASP, jQuery, Ajax etc).  I've installed VS 2010 and have IIS running on my W7 64bit PC.

I've created a new web project (in a folder called C:\ASP.NET Testing\ASP.NET 4.0 Examples) called ASP.NET-4.0.

I can compile the project fine and run the default page etc.

I am trying to load in a simple example from a book (ASP.NET 4.0 In Practice).  So, I've created a sub folder CH01, and then copied in the .aspx and .aspx.vb files.

When I debug this, I get

```
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'ASP.NET_4._0.Global_asax'.

Source Error: 

 Line 1:  <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.vb" Inherits="ASP.NET_4._0.Global_asax" Language="vb" %>
```

in the browser window.

The sample code (which has been downloaded from the website) is :

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="1-4.aspx.vb" Inherits="_1_4" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Listing 1.4</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="Form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:literal id="ResponseText" runat="server" />
            <br />
            Enter your name:
            <asp:textbox runat="server" ID="Name" />
            <br />
            <asp:button runat="server" Text="Click Me" ID="ClickButton" OnClick="HandleSubmit" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and

```
Partial Class _1_4
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Sub HandleSubmit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        ResponseText.Text = "Your name is: " & Name.Text
    End Sub

End Class
```

In VS, I also get an error message highlighting the ResponseText.Text = "Your name is: " & Name.Text

```
'ResponseText' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
```

Global.asxa file

```
Imports System.Web.SessionState

Public Class Global_asax
    Inherits System.Web.HttpApplication

    Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        ' Fires when the application is started
    End Sub

    Sub Session_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        ' Fires when the session is started
    End Sub

    Sub Application_BeginRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        ' Fires at the beginning of each request
    End Sub

    Sub Application_AuthenticateRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        ' Fires upon attempting to authenticate the use
    End Sub

    Sub Application_Error(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        ' Fires when an error occurs
    End Sub

    Sub Session_End(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        ' Fires when the session ends
    End Sub

    Sub Application_End(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        ' Fires when the application ends
    End Sub

End Class
```

I'm obviously missing something really simple, but I don't get it.  I can't see any instructions as to anything which I need to set within VS.

Thanks.

This page works OK if I add from VS.  In effect the same page as I'm copying in from the examples, but with slight changes to the page tag.  It alos has a .designer.vb page which was automatically generated by VS.

```
14.aspx
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="14.aspx.vb" Inherits="ASP.NET_4._0._14" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<title>Listing 1.4</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="Form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:literal id="ResponseText" runat="server" />
            <br />
            Enter your name:
            <asp:textbox runat="server" ID="Name" />
            <br />
            <asp:button runat="server" Text="Click Me" ID="ClickButton" OnClick="HandleSubmit" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

14.aspx.vb
Public Class _14                                                                                
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page                                                                 

    Sub HandleSubmit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)                              
        ResponseText.Text = "Your name is: " & Name.Text                                        
    End Sub                                                                                     

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub                                                                                     

End Class

14.aspx.designer.vb
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                         
' <auto-generated>                                                               
'     This code was generated by a tool.                                         
'                                                                                
'     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if      
'     the code is regenerated.                                                   
' </auto-generated>                                                              
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------  

Option Strict On                                                                 
Option Explicit On                                                               


Partial Public Class _14                                                         

    '''<summary>                                                                 
    '''Form1 control.                                                            
    '''</summary>                                                                
    '''<remarks>                                                                 
    '''Auto-generated field.                                                     
    '''To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.  
    '''</remarks>                                                                
    Protected WithEvents Form1 As Global.System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm     

    '''<summary>                                                                 
    '''ResponseText control.                                                     
    '''</summary>                                                                
    '''<remarks>                                                                 
    '''Auto-generated field.                                                     
    '''To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.  
    '''</remarks>                                                                
    Protected WithEvents ResponseText As Global.System.Web.UI.WebControls.Literal

    '''<summary>                                                                 
    '''Name control.                                                             
    '''</summary>                                                                
    '''<remarks>                                                                 
    '''Auto-generated field.                                                     
    '''To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.  
    '''</remarks>                                                                
    Protected WithEvents Name As Global.System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox        

    '''<summary>                                                                 
    '''ClickButton control.                                                      
    '''</summary>                                                                
    '''<remarks>                                                                 
    '''Auto-generated field.                                                     
    '''To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.  
    '''</remarks>                                                                
    Protected WithEvents ClickButton As Global.System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button  
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Check you `global.asax` on the root of your website. There seems to be something wrong with the class name/namespace. I don't think it has anything to do with the file you added, but rather with something you probably moved or removed by mistake.

Comment: I haven't touched the global.asax file. If I remove the files added, everything works fine.  I wondered if it's anything to with the inherits statement?

Comment: just have a look at it. .net cannot find the class name. what is the class name in global.asax?

Comment: I've added the global.asxa contents now to the post.

Comment: you can see then that the class name is `Global_asax` and not `ASP.NET_4._0.Global_asax`. So, as I said there is a problem with the namespace. change the class name to `ASP.NET_4._0.Global_asax`

Comment: I've changed the global.asax file to Public Class ASP.NET_4._0.Global_asax .  However, VS now underlines the characters after the ASP, and the error says End Of Statement Expected.  Are there restrictions on project names?

Comment: @Keith - You have posted your `Global.asax.vb` code. If you look carefully at `Solution Explorer` in `Visual Studio`, there should be an arrow next to `Global.asax`. If you click on it it will expand and you'll see that you have at least 2 files: `Global.asax` & `Global.asax.vb`. So, go to `Global.asax` and change the `Inherits` attribute at Line 1 to `Global_asax`, then go to `Global.asax.vb` and set the class name to `Global_asax` as well.

Comment: Hi Ted.  I've created a new page in the same folder by VS.  Then copied the code in the .aspx and .aspx.vb pages from the original page to the new page (only changes were the class name/codebehind/inherits info in the page tag).  After excluding the problem page, I was then able to build the project fine.  I noticed though that the new page had a aspx.designer.vb page as well.  As the original page I imported from the book examples didn't work, is this the cause of the problem?  I think the global.asax is OK, as the solution builds when the imported file is excluded.

Comment: What namespace did VS give to the new class ?

Comment: I've added the new page details in the original post.  It's called 14.aspx and not 1-4.aspx.  It also has the additional .designer.vb page which I don't have for the example page which I was trying to add to the project.

Comment: So, the default namespace of your project seems to be `ASP.NET_4._0` but the file you copied over had a different one. That was your problem.

Comment: I've just sorted it.  The problem is that when I add the file to the project, I need to then right mouse click on the file within VS and select 'Convert To Web Application'.  This then forces the creation of the .designer.vb page and it works.  Thanks for your help Ted, much appreciated.